# I can not add in Hashtable

Tags: c#, hashtable

First, sorry for my bad english.

I have this:

```
public static Users server = new Users();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    server.addNewUser(1, "John");
    server.addNewUser(2, "Marlon");
    server.addNewUser(3, "Lucas");
    Console.WriteLine(server.countUsers()); //COUNT USERS

    TcpManager manager = new TcpManager(58636, 500);

    Console.Read();
}
```

TcpManager:

```
public Users test = new Users();
internal TcpManager(int port, int maxuserson)
{
    test.addNewUser(4, "Julio");
    test.addNewUser(5, "Marcelo");
    test.addNewUser(6, "Andre");
    Console.WriteLine(test.countUsers()); //COUNT USERS
}
```

and my Users class:

```
class Users
{
    Hashtable users = new Hashtable();

    public void addNewUser(int id, string name)
    {
        if (!users.ContainsKey(id))
            users.Add(id, name);
        else users[id] = name;
    }

    public int countUsers()
    {
        return users.Count;
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I add a User on Main, it works!
But when I try to do the same in TcpManager, he simply does not add.

How to make it work?
I tried with List, Dictionary, Tuple, all with same problem.

My first ConsoleWrite return "3", and second in TcpManager return "3" too, when should return "6".

Thank you all, and again, sorry for my English.

Comment: Why should it return 6? The objects test and server are independent, with independent hash tables. Adding to one doesn't add to the other?

Comment: The main method and the TcpManager are using different instances of `Users`. The main method uses a static instance whereas the TcpManager uses a local member instance. At first call from TcpManager  the hashtable is empty. Pass the static instance to the `TcpManager` and it should work.

Comment: I'm trying to create a list of users that can be accessed and added anywhere in the code, i tried create a STATIC VOID in TcpManager, and add users, and not work..

Comment: Is there any easier way for me to create a list of data from multiple users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the Hashtable in the `Users` class as an instance-field. this means every instance of `Users` has its own hashtable. Therefore, you program behaves just as one would expect.

There are several ways to make it work the way you want.

### Make `Users` static

```
static class Users
{
    private static Hashtable users;

    static Users()
    {
       users = new Hashtable();
    }

    public static void addNewUser(int id, string name)
    {
        if (!users.ContainsKey(id))
            users.Add(id, name);
        else users[id] = name;
    }

    public static int countUsers()
    {
        return users.Count;
    }    
}
```

#### Usage

```
Users.addNewUser(1, "Vera");
Console.WriteLine(Users.countUsers());
```

### Make use users `Hashable` static (Essentially, this is the Monostate-Pattern)

```
class Users
{
    private static Hashtable users = new HashTable();

    public void addNewUser(int id, string name)
    {
        if (!users.ContainsKey(id))
            users.Add(id, name);
        else users[id] = name;
    }

    public int countUsers()
    {
        return users.Count;
    }    
}
```

#### Usage

```
var users = new Users();
users .addNewUser(1, "Vera");
Console.WriteLine(users.countUsers());
```

### Use Singleton

```
class Users
{
    private Hashtable users;

    private static Users instance;

    private Users()
    {
         users = new HashTable();
    }

    public static Users Instance 
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance=new Users();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void addNewUser(int id, string name)
    {
        if (!users.ContainsKey(id))
            users.Add(id, name);
        else users[id] = name;
    }

    public int countUsers()
    {
        return users.Count;
    }    
}
```

#### Usage

`Users.Instance` is the only instance of users that will ever be created, since the ctor is private and only used in the `Instance`-Property.

```
var users = Users.Instance;
users.addNewUser(1, "Vera");
users.countUsers();
```

Comment: Oh god, I tried everything, and this works. Many thanks! :D

Comment: ill add some more to my answer for u to notice, there are some other issues

Comment: Thank you, again .. now it got a lot easier,

Answer (score 1):

try with this way:

```cs
TcpManager manager = new TcpManager(58636, 500);

test.addNewUser(4, "Julio");
test.addNewUser(5, "Marcelo");
test.addNewUser(6, "Andre");

Console.WriteLine(manager.test.countUsers()); // 6
```

in TcpManager constructor:

```cs
internal TcpManager(int port, int maxuserson)
{
    // This code will executed when you call  new TcpManager();
    // So, you have to add 1, 2 and 3 ids first.
    manager.test.addNewUser(1, "John");
    manager.test.addNewUser(2, "Marlon");
    manager.test.addNewUser(3, "Lucas");
    Console.WriteLine(test.countUsers()); //COUNT USERS: 3
}
```